DIY BLDC motor control problem
I have made an esc (electronic speed controller) on a PCB prototyping board with sensorless, 6-step trapezoidal (unipolar synchronous switching) using the Nucleo G431 board. I am sensing back EMF with ADC to detect zero cross. At 100% duty, the motor is drawing huge current and getting stuck while damaging the motor. How do I resolve the issue?
If the esc hardware is being developed on a PCB, just like SimonK 30 A ESC, will the problem be solved?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
